# can't connect android Spydroid to wowza

Tags: android, wowza

since last two weeks i am trying android spydroid framework to wowza media server 3 but i failed. I even followed their links 
  http://code.google.com/p/spydroid-ipcamera/issues/detail?id=20

but all failed. But Spydroid is streaming successfully with rstp://ip:8086/ to my PC vlc player. Its failing to stream to wowza server. Here is what i did

1. installed spydroid 1.6
2. Started the app and uploaded the spydroid.sdp to [wowza-install-dir]/content
3. created an application rtplive in wowza by following this link:
   http://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?36-How-to-set-up-live-streaming-using-an-RTMP-based-encoder
4. lastly i'm trying to play the stream through vlc
   But its showing cant't open the stream error.

I case anybody have managed to connect and stream to wowza please share . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you reached out to the Wowza support team yet?  They may have some ideas for you.  You'd need to either post on the Wowza forums or send mail to support [at] wowza.com.

-Chris

Comment: Yes I did asked wowza support but they don't provide any Java based client side SDK at the moment. All of their support is for Flash development environment